I am not able to get the response from the aws
I am trying to integrate AWS transcribe streaming in a websocket using python as a backend language. I will be sending PCM 16 bit 24kHz audio chunks as input from the client(frontend). I am not able to get the response from the aws.
Here is my code -
from amazon_transcribe.client import TranscribeStreamingClient
from amazon_transcribe.handlers import TranscriptResultStreamHandler
from amazon_transcribe.model import TranscriptEvent
import websockets
from flask import Flask
import os
import json
 
# from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import asyncio
 
app = Flask(__name__)
# socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")
client = TranscribeStreamingClient(region="something")
os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = "key"
os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = "secret"
clients = []
 
 
# Start transcription to generate our async stream
# stream = client.start_stream_transcription(
#     language_code="en-US",
#     media_sample_rate_hz=16000,
#     media_encoding="pcm"
# )
async def write_chunks(stream, data):
    # This connects the raw audio chunks generator coming from the microphone
    # and passes them along to the transcription stream.
    async for chunk in data:
        await stream.input_stream.send_audio_event(audio_chunk=chunk)
    await stream.input_stream.end_stream()
 
 
class MyEventHandler(TranscriptResultStreamHandler):
    async def handle_transcript_event(self, transcript_event: TranscriptEvent):
        # This handler can be implemented to handle transcriptions as needed.
        # Here's an example to get started.
        results = transcript_event.transcript.results
        for result in results:
            for alt in result.alternatives:
                print(alt.transcript)
 
 
async def handle_client(websocket, path):
    print(websocket)
    print(path)
        # Wait for messages from the client
    async for message in websocket:
        # If there are at least two clients, forward the message
        message = json.loads(message)
        print(message.keys())
        stream = await client.start_stream_transcription(
            language_code="en-US",
            media_sample_rate_hz=24000,
            media_encoding="pcm"
        )
        handler = MyEventHandler(stream.output_stream)
        # # This connects the raw audio chunks generator coming from the microphone
        # # and passes them along to the transcription stream.
        if message['type'] == 'input_audio_buffer.append':
            await asyncio.gather(write_chunks(stream, message['audio']), handler.handle_events())
        await websocket.send(json.dumps("success"))
    # except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
    #     print("Client disconnected")

    # finally:
    # Unregister client
    # clients.remove(websocket)
    
 
 
async def main():
    server = await websockets.serve(handle_client, "localhost", 8282, max_size=10**8, subprotocols=[
        'realtime',
        'openai-insecure-api-key.null',
        'openai-beta.realtime-v1'
    ])
    await server.wait_closed()
 
 
asyncio.run(main())

the messages are sent successfully from the frontend but not able to receive the message on backend in the above socket.
Trying to find a way to use streaming transcription api of aws
